# no such partition, grub rescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I am currently dual booting Win7 and Ubuntu.  I created a new partition, on my c drive, to install windows 8 on (i did not want to do the upgrade).  I inserted the windows 8 cd and restarted my computer.  no such partition/ grub rescue is all that comes up now.  I loaded ubuntu from disk and did boot-repair.  It did not solve my problem but I got the [following output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1349256)

Please let me know if anyone can fix this.  I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

You have no ext4 or ext2 partitions at all, but you do have 5 NTFS partitions.  Is one of them where you installed Ubuntu?  If it's /dev/sdc1 then you should follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) to re-install grub.

It really is better to use an ext4 partition when you install Ubuntu or any other Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue >
```

This error probably due to one of the 2 cases:

- Case 1: Created disk partition in Windows.
- Case 2: GRUB damaged by some accidental actions like deleting the partition that contains grub bootloader.

In your case you are in Case 1. Just enter the commands in your rescue window one-by-one:

```
> ls
(output like (hd0),(hd0,msdos1),(hd0,msdos2))
> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(output like Unknown file system which means grub not found in the device. Retry with other partition. Follow next..)
> ls (hd0,msdos2)
(output like ext2 or ext3 . This is the drive where grub is found)
> set root=(hd0,msdos2)
> set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
> insmod normal
normal
(You enter into a window that shows list of operating systems)
```

Then login to Ubuntu and enter the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Thats it. You are fixed. When you are in a dual boot you must not make disk partitions in Windows.